# UINavigationController inside UITabBarController with react-native

Tags: android, ios, tabs, navigation, react-native

I'm trying to create a tab based application in which one of the tab is a `UINavigationController`like view. I mean from this tab I want to be able to push a new view from the right of the screen but the TabBar must no be hidden by this new view.

On iOS, I would just use a `UINavigationController` as one of a `TabBarController` tabs.

Right now I have a `Navigator` with a `renderScene`:

```
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    if (route.modal) {
      const modals = {
        selectPark: <SQSelectParkView navigator={navigator} handleBack={() => navigator.pop()}/>
      }
      return modals[route.modal];
    }
    return <SQNavigationView navigator={navigator} />;
  }
```

This `Navigator` renders modal views or returns my app's main view: `SQNavigationView`.

`SQNavigationView` is the tabbed view:

```
  render() {
    const { navigator, park } = this.props;
    const { tabs } = this.state;

    const items = Object.keys(tabs).map(title =>
      <TabBarIOS.Item
        key={title}
        title={title}
        selected={this.props.tab === title}
        onPress={this.props.onTabSelect.bind(this, title)}>
        {tabs[title]}
      </TabBarIOS.Item>
    );

    return (
      <TabBarIOS>
        {items}
      </TabBarIOS>
    )
  }
```

Where `this.state.tabs` is just a dictionary of `String: <View>` right now. The `selected` tab comes from `redux-connect`:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    tab: state.navigation.tab
  };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onTabSelect: (tab) => dispatch(Actions.navigation.switchTab(tab))
  };
}
```

Which I push with:

```
this.props.navigator.push({modal: 'selectPark'});
```

#### Questions

- How can I implement the `UINavigationController` like in those `TabBarIOS.Item` ?

If the solution is to use an other `Navigator`:

- How can I use the `Navigator` with `redux-connect` ?
- What will be the life cycle of my views if I change the selected tab ?

#### Note

This is a cross-platform project. I use `DrawerLayoutAndroid` instead of `TabBarIOS` on android.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but If you haven't already you might check out [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation). I believe it allows you to push a view without obstructing the tabs. Another one to look at is [NavigationExperimental](https://github.com/ericvicenti/navigation-rfc) which will eventually replace the navigation library in React Native.